# Checking for a empty Input (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Afternoon all, I have built a simple check to see if an input is empty or `null` on my html page. If that input is empty it should change the value of another input that is hidden, but for some reason or another; it's just returning the else statement even if the first argument is true.

I'm not incredibly skilled with Javascript but I can feel my way around most of the time. A second set of eyes would be quite helpful, to check and see if I overlooked any syntax errors.

```
var adjVar = document.getElementById('richaccvar'); // el in question

if (adjVar && adjVar.value) { // argument check
    document.getElementsByName('adjvar')[0].value= 'Has Input!'; // true response
} else {
    document.getElementsByName('adjvar')[0].value= 'Null Input!'; // false response
};
```

**Requested Materials**
(This is bloated HTML)

```
    <script>$( document ).ready(function() {$('#pdfimage').click(function() {   $('#corexsave').val('false');   $('#corexsaveorder').val('false');  senddata(); setTimeout(function (){     window.open( '/aspire/preview?mode=edit&template=19689&dt=20065&mime=application/pdf&t=1475155102355&print=false&t=' + Math.random(), '_blank');    }, 100); });$('.saveasbutton').click(function() {var text = $('#documentname').val();if (text == '') { alert('Document name can not be blank.'); }else{$('#corexdoctitle').val(text); $('.saveorder').removeAttr('disabled'); $('.savebutton').removeAttr('disabled'); $('#corexsave').val('true');$('#corexsaveorder').val('false');senddata();$('#corexsave').val('false');$('#corexsaveorder').val('false');senddata();$('#newdocmodal').modal('hide'); };});});</script>    
    <script type="text/javascript"> function loadstuff() {// ---
var x = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris gravida, lectus quis aliquam dapibus, neque mi elementum ipsum, ac ultricies leo ipsum ac felis. Fusce varius quam id dui eleifend, at porttitor sem commodo. Phasellus ut imperdiet diam, nec eleifend arcu. Pellentesque non ornare massa, id imperdiet nulla.<br/><br/>Phasellus sed imperdiet neque, non varius nisi. Phasellus feugiat, dolor id varius consequat, justo nisi efficitur neque, ut sagittis nunc tortor nec nunc. Ut dignissim ullamcorper sapien, sed aliquet nunc auctor ut. Nam vel ipsum vel lectus fringilla tempor ut vitae nunc.<br/><br/>Nullam in venenatis turpis. Duis id ex nunc. Proin libero lectus, cursus ac interdum ac, aliquet eu urna. Donec sed pulvinar neque. In tellus nulla, vulputate eget sollicitudin vel, placerat eu ex. Nam non sollicitudin odio. Aliquam vulputate diam ut erat rutrum, quis scelerisque risus ornare.<br/><br/><b>Exterior</b><br/>Donec eu efficitur urna. Ut vitae dictum tellus, ut luctus justo. Nam suscipit sem ut risus bibendum varius. Donec eget quam nec turpis rhoncus euismod in at justo. Aliquam lobortis quam nec nulla posuere sagittis. Pellentesque malesuada vehicula sem, nec vestibulum dui iaculis sit amet. Morbi diam ipsum, congue ut turpis vulputate, dictum sagittis orci.<br/><br/>Vestibulum rhoncus nulla vel vestibulum feugiat. Fusce lobortis molestie pretium. Sed nec metus sed tellus luctus euismod in et arcu. Integer justo tortor, mollis ut eros vel, gravida molestie urna.<br/><br/><b>Location</b><br/>Sed aliquet lorem eu dapibus faucibus. Vivamus eu nibh in tellus tristique finibus vel eget nisi. Nam ultricies, nisi sed rutrum mattis, lacus metus gravida nisi, a interdum dui libero ac ligula. Etiam nec consectetur justo. In feugiat magna ac fringilla auctor. Curabitur sit amet consequat orci. Sed feugiat nisi at metus bibendum sagittis.<br/><br/>Donec non posuere leo, hendrerit tristique eros. Nam scelerisque risus non velit cursus accumsan. Vivamus nec semper tellus, nec vulputate orci. Nam sed augue nec augue tristique ornare ac nec augue. Vestibulum volutpat pulvinar felis malesuada gravida. Phasellus egestas consectetur feugiat. Proin ac justo nunc.<br/><br/><b>Services</b><br/>Maecenas facilisis urna eget elit gravida elementum. Integer enim nisl, dictum eu eros sollicitudin, vestibulum pretium dui. Aenean leo quam, sollicitudin eget egestas vitae, commodo eu nulla. Aliquam consectetur mauris vel aliquet venenatis. Vestibulum purus felis, tempor eu quam eget, tincidunt placerat odio.<br/><br/>Pellentesque vel rutrum erat. Nulla fringilla dui eu volutpat suscipit. Mauris purus nisl, consequat ac ipsum eu, tempor bibendum lectus. Suspendisse sollicitudin turpis ligula, et lacinia felis efficitur porta. Nunc in nulla mauris. Sed feugiat mauris eget ipsum maximus, tempor semper justo facilisis. Pellentesque elementum, justo ut fermentum blandit, urna justo ultrices augue, in placerat tortor tortor at justo.<br/><br/><b>Local Authority</b><br/>Dacorum Borough Council, Civic Centre, Marlowes Hemel Hempstead, Hertfordshire HP1 1HH<br/>Tel: 01442 228000<br/><br/>Council Tax Band: F<br/><br/><b>Directions</b><br/>Sed aliquet lorem eu dapibus faucibus. Vivamus eu nibh in tellus tristique finibus vel eget nisi. Nam ultricies, nisi sed rutrum mattis, lacus metus gravida nisi, a interdum dui libero ac ligula. Etiam nec consectetur justo. In feugiat magna ac fringilla auctor. Curabitur sit amet consequat orci. Sed feugiat nisi at metus bibendum sagittis.<br/><br/>Donec non posuere leo, hendrerit tristique eros. Nam scelerisque risus non velit cursus accumsan. Vivamus nec semper tellus, nec vulputate orci. Nam sed augue nec augue tristique ornare ac nec augue. Vestibulum volutpat pulvinar felis malesuada gravida. Phasellus egestas consectetur feugiat. Proin ac justo nunc. '; 

document.getElementById('richbluvar').value = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris gravida, lectus quis aliquam dapibus, neque mi elementum ipsum, ac ultricies leo ipsum ac felis. Fusce varius quam id dui eleifend, at porttitor sem commodo. Phasellus ut imperdiet diam, nec eleifend arcu. Pellentesque non ornare massa, id imperdiet nulla. Phasellus sed imperdiet neque, non varius nisi.';
document.getElementById('richsitvar').value = 'Exampleton 1½ miles, Mainline Station (Express 30 Minutes) 1½ miles, M0 4 miles, M01 4½ miles, Exampleshire 4¾ miles.';
document.getElementById('richaccvar1').value = 'Nullam, Lectus, Quis, Aliquam, Dapibus, Neque, Mi, Elementum, Ipsum, Ac, Ultricies, Leo, Ipsum, Ac, Felis, Fusce, Varius, Quam, Id, Dui.';
document.getElementById('richaccvar2').value = 'Nullam, Venenatis, Turpis, Duis, Ex, Nunc, Proin, Libero, Lectus, Elementum, Ipsum, Ac, Ultricies, Leo, Ipsum, Ac, Felis, Fusce, Varius, Quam, Id, Dui, Eleifend, At, Porttitor, Sem, Commodo.';
document.getElementById('richaccvar3').value = 'Nullam, Venenatis, Turpis, Duis, Ex, Nunc, Proin, Libero, Lectus, Quis, Aliquam, Dapibus, Neque, Mi.';
document.getElementById('richbdyvar').value = x;

// ---
document.getElementsByName('pnvar')[0].placeholder='Example ; Poppy Mannor';
document.getElementsByName('plvar')[0].placeholder='Example ; Agloe, Hertfordshire';
document.getElementsByName('telvar')[0].placeholder='Example ; +44 (0)1234 567 890';
document.getElementsByName('faxvar')[0].placeholder='Example ; +44 (0)1234 567 890 (Optional)';
document.getElementsByName('add1')[0].placeholder='Example ; 123 Tessry Lane';
document.getElementsByName('add2')[0].placeholder='Example ; Example Ave.';
document.getElementsByName('couvar')[0].placeholder='Example ; Hertfordshire';
document.getElementsByName('ctyvar')[0].placeholder='Example ; Exampleton';
document.getElementsByName('pstvar')[0].placeholder='Example ; EX0 7LE';
document.getElementsByName('emavar')[0].placeholder='Example ; guest@argroup.co.uk';
document.getElementsByName('revvar')[0].placeholder='Example ; EEE1234/6789012 EXA/MPLE';
// ---
var adjVar = document.getElementById('richaccvar');

if (adjVar && adjVar.value) {
    document.getElementsByName('adjvar')[0].value= 'Has Input!';
} else {
    document.getElementsByName('adjvar')[0].value= 'Null Input!';
};} </script>   
    <script>function senddata() {$("#bluvar").val($('#richbluvar').code());$("#sitvar").val($('#richsitvar').code());$("#accvar").val($('#richaccvar').code());$("#accvar1").val($('#richaccvar1').code());$("#accvar2").val($('#richaccvar2').code());$("#accvar3").val($('#richaccvar3').code());$("#accvar4").val($('#richaccvar4').code());$("#accvar5").val($('#richaccvar5').code());$("#accvar6").val($('#richaccvar6').code());$("#bdyvar").val($('#richbdyvar').code());   var arrayData, objectData;    var proofurl = '/aspire/preview?mode=edit&template=19689&dt=20065&width=' + $('#coreximagewidth').val();  arrayData = $('#form').serializeArray();    $.ajax({        type: 'POST',       url: '/aspire/preview?template=19689&dt=20065&document=' + $('#corexdocumentid').val(),     data: arrayData,        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',        dataType: 'json',       success: function(data) {           $('#previewimage').attr('src', proofurl +'&t=' + Math.random());            $('#previewimage').load(function() {                $(this).show();  if( $(this).parents('.sticky-wrapper').length === 0 ) {$(".js-sticky-image").sticky({ topSpacing:80, bottomSpacing: 80});var minHeight = $(".seq-interactive-image img").height() + 20 + 60; $('.seq-product-editor-main').css({'min-height' : minHeight });}          }).each(function(){ if(this.complete) { $(this).trigger('load');  } });             if (data != null) {                 var obj = data.responseText;                if (obj.indexOf('documentid:') === 0) {                 $('#corexdocumentid').val(obj);                 if ($('#corexsaveorder').val() == 'true') {                     $('#corexsaveorder').val(false);            window.location.replace( '/aspire/OrderSelect.jsp?sp=' + $('#corexproductid').val() + '&sp=' + $('#corexdocumentid').val() , '');           }               }else{                  $('#corexsaveorder').val(false);                }           }       },      error: function(data) {             var obj = data.responseText;            if (obj.indexOf('documentid:') === 0) {             $('#corexdocumentid').val(obj);             if ($('#corexsaveorder').val() == 'true') {                 $('#corexsaveorder').val(false);        window.location.replace( '/aspire/OrderSelect.jsp?sp=' + $('#corexproductid').val() + '&sp=' + $('#corexdocumentid').val().replace('documentid:', ''));     }           }else{              $('#previewimage').attr('src', proofurl + '&t=' + Math.random());               $('#previewimage').load(function() {                    $(this).show(); if( $(this).parents('.sticky-wrapper').length === 0 ) {$(".js-sticky-image").sticky({ topSpacing:80, bottomSpacing: 80});var minHeight = $(".seq-interactive-image img").height() + 20 + 60; $('.seq-product-editor-main').css({'min-height' : minHeight });}               }).each(function(){ if(this.complete) { $(this).trigger('load');  } });                 $('#errorlist').hide();             $('#errorlist').empty();               if (obj != null && obj != '') {                  $('#errorlist').append(obj);                    $('#errorlist').show();             }           }       }   });   if ($('#corexdoctitle').val() == '') {        $('#savebutton').hide();        $('#saveorder').hide(); }else{      $('#savebutton').show();        $('#saveorder').show(); };}$( document ).ready(function() { senddata(); });</script>

<span>

</span>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        loadstuff(); 
    </script>



                      <!-- end header banner -->
                </div> <!-- end page content wrapper inner -->
             </div>  <!-- end page content wrapper -->
        </span>

    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
tapestry.addOnLoad(function(e) {
dojo.require("tapestry.form");tapestry.form.registerForm("mainsearch");

tapestry.form.focusField('menu-search-field');});
// --></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `adjvar` element?

Comment: @Satpal Simple HTML text input.

Comment: Show the HTML and when you are executing the above statement?

Comment: Instead of && use ||

Comment: use  `&& adjVar.value != ''`

Comment: @priya_singh: That would be incorrect. When the element itself is `null`, it would try to get `null.value`.

Comment: @Beaniie: Can't know without you providing a complete demo that reproduces the problem. Could be that you're fetching the `richaccvar` before the DOM is loaded. You need to debug this by using `console.log()` to check your values. This would be the first step when dealing with such issues.

Comment: All adjust the question to reflect your request.

Comment: Try using `innerHTML` instead of `value` to update the value.

Comment: @DCruz22 I can't believe I didn't think of that... I'll give it ago and let you know.

Comment: @DCruz22: That would be incorrect. Input elements have no use for `.innerHTML`. The OP is doing it correctly.

Comment: @squint I thought you could.

Comment: @Beaniie: That's only for elements that can have a subtree beneath them. Input elements have no opportunity to have child nodes, so `innerHTML` and `textContent` have no effect. Getting the `input` value is done via `.value`.

Comment: @squint TIL ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I´d check for the length of the string:

```
var adjVar = document.getElementById('richaccvar').value;
if (adjVar.length >0) {
  document.getElementsByName('adjvar')[0].value= 'Has Input!'; // true response
} else {
    document.getElementsByName('adjvar')[0].value= 'Null Input!'; // false response
};
```

maybe also cut the spaces before

Comment: Checking the length is no different, and you're not checking for the element first. The OP's original code is better.

Answer (score 0):

Change the if condition to

```
if (adjVar != null && adjVar.value != '')
```

Also if you HTML with class name as advar is not an input but a div then you should use `innerHTML` instead of `value`  to set the value

```js
function check() {

var adjVar = document.getElementById('richaccvar'); // el in question
console.log(adjVar);
if (adjVar != null && adjVar.value != '') { // argument check
    console.log('true');
    console.log()
    document.getElementsByClassName('adjvar')[0].innerHTML= 'Has Input!'; // true response
} else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('adjvar')[0].innerHTML= 'Null Input!'; // false response
};
  
  }
```

```html
<input type = "text" id="richaccvar" onBlur="check()"/>
<div class="adjvar"></div>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way the condition is currently written. Why would they need to change it? And why do you assume it's not `getElementsByName`?

Comment: I've been using `getElementsByName` for quite some time perfectly fine. I've also seen it listed in other scripts too.

Comment: [MDN `getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Comment: @squint Yeah you are right, I was mistaken about that. I removed it from the question

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want an onchange event to see if the input was changed.

```
var adjVar = document.getElementById('richaccvar'); // el in question

adjVar.onchange = function () {

    if (adjVar.value) { // argument check
        document.getElementsByName('adjvar')[0].value= 'Has Input!'; // true response
    } else {
        document.getElementsByName('adjvar')[0].value= 'Null Input!'; // false response
    };
};
```

Comment: I tested this theory after researching it a little. With `onchange` I loose all argument function completely.